# php var isset, ?data=menu

Tags: php, get, isset

I have script where some url leads to index.php?data and the page opens
how can I use that to use the url open an "subpage" like index.php?data=menu or so?
the code I use with the first one is

`if(isset($_GET['palvelut'])){ echo "this is a sample"; }`

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea, but allow me to elaborate at little on this. You need to check if `$_GET['data']` is set, by doing `isset($_GET['data'])`, and if that is set, checking to see if it has a given value, "menu" in this case. You can do that like this `$_GET['data'] == "menu"`. Putting it all together, you get this:

```
if (isset($_GET['data']) && $_GET['data'] == "menu") {
    /* Menu code goes here */
}
```

If you would like to have this work for multiple values for `data` you can do the following:

```
if (isset($_GET['data'])) {
  switch($_GET['data']) {
    case "Possible_Value_1" :
      /* Code for this condition appears here */
      break;

    case "Possible_Value_2" :
      /* Code for this condition appears here */
      break;

    /* etc... */

    default :
      //Just as a precaution...
      echo "Invalid 'data' value supplied!";
      break;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 You're typing fast! 17 seconds faster than me for the same answer.. I'm out.

Comment: well yes :)
that palvelut where a typo.. but this and all other answerr helped. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question (which I don't), you've answered it already.

Your URL is: **http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?data=something**

Your code would be:

```
if (!isset($_GET['data'])) {
  //do something because no data argument was passed
} else {
  switch ($_GET['data']) {  
     case "homepage":
       header("location: homepage.php");
       die;
       break;
     case "someotherpage":
       header("location: someotherpage.php");
       die;
       break;
     //and so on
  }
}
```

Obviously instead of using a header redirect, you might just require() or include() a file, or do something else entirely.

Comment: This.  To the original question author though: this switch statement will do the redirect perfectly, but if you DON'T do this method and use something similar, like storing the _GET in a variable, and then redirecting to that variable, you need to sanitize the input to prevent injection.

Comment: what do you mean?
when browsing http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?data=something
and when that something is called the variable is being set and when going to another page the varable is cleaned.
I used the first one up there @spryno724

`if (isset($_GET['data']) && $_GET['data'] == "menu") {
    /* Menu code goes here */
}`

I use else if on my script'